# my code keeps printing 'Hi [{“FirstName”:“Martin”}]'. how can I fix this?

Tags: node.js, mariadb

```
async secondStep(step) {
    step.values.id = step.result;
    try{
        let conn = await pool.getConnection();
        const firstName = await conn.query('SELECT FirstName FROM partners where ID = ' + step.values.id);
        const lastName = await conn.query('SELECT LastName FROM partners where ID = ' + step.values.id);
        // const partner = new MyUser(firstName, lastName, step.values.id);
        console.log(firstName);
        //var msg = `Hi ${firstName[0]}`;
        var msg = `Hi ${JSON.stringify(firstName)}`;
        await step.context.sendActivity(msg);
        endDialog = true;
        return await step.endDialog();
    }catch(err){

    }
}
```

I want my bot to respond with "Hi Martin."
Instead it prints 'Hi[{“FirstName”:“Martin”}]'
how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `conn.query()` resolves in an array of objects, where each object represents a row.

So your `firstName` already contains the `[{“FirstName”:“Martin”}]` array.

I recommend naming the variable in a way that better represents the returned value. For example `firstNameResult`.

Then you can do:

```
const firstNameResult = await conn.query('SELECT FirstName FROM partners where ID = ' + step.values.id);
const firstName = firstNameResult[0]['FirstName'];
var msg = `Hi ${firstName}`;
```

---

Mind that it's safer to use [prepared statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries) instead of concatenating parts of the SQL query together.